# how to print out all males with name that begin with A - C using lambda expression

Tags: java, list, lambda

I'm currently studying the concept of lambda on java tutorial oracle. To practice with the concept of lambda, I'm trying to come up with lambda code that print out all males with name that begin with A to C. However, I can't figure out what code to write after `->` in the lambda expression. Could someone please help me out? Thanks in advance for any help!

```
public static void printPerson(List<Person> listOfPerson, CheckPerson tester){
    for(Person p : listOfPerson){
        if(tester.test(p)){
            p.printPerson();
        }
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Person> roster = Person.createRoster();
    for (Person p : roster) {
        p.printPerson();
    }

    System.out.println("5.1 lambda male name begin with a - c");
    RosterTest.printPerson(roster, 
            (Person p) -> 
                    ????????????????
            );
}
```

Person class:

```
public class Person {

    public enum Sex {
        MALE, FEMALE
    }

    String name; 
    LocalDate birthday;
    Sex gender;
    String emailAddress;

    Person(String nameArg, LocalDate birthdayArg,
        Sex genderArg, String emailArg) {
        name = nameArg;
        birthday = birthdayArg;
        gender = genderArg;
        emailAddress = emailArg;
    }  

    public int getAge() {
        return birthday
            .until(IsoChronology.INSTANCE.dateNow())
            .getYears();
    }

    public String toString(){
        return name + " " + birthday + " " + gender;
    }

    public void printPerson() {
      System.out.println(name + ", " + this.getAge());
    }

    public Sex getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getEmailAddress() {
        return emailAddress;
    }

    public LocalDate getBirthday() {
        return birthday;
    }

    public static int compareByAge(Person a, Person b) {
        return a.birthday.compareTo(b.birthday);
    }

    public static List<Person> createRoster() {

        List<Person> roster = new ArrayList<>();
        roster.add(
            new Person(
            "Fred",
            IsoChronology.INSTANCE.date(1980, 6, 20),
            Person.Sex.MALE,
            "fred@example.com"));
        roster.add(
            new Person(
            "Jane",
            IsoChronology.INSTANCE.date(1990, 7, 15),
            Person.Sex.FEMALE, "jane@example.com"));
        roster.add(
            new Person(
            "George",
            IsoChronology.INSTANCE.date(1991, 8, 13),
            Person.Sex.MALE, "george@example.com"));
        roster.add(
            new Person(
            "Bob",
            IsoChronology.INSTANCE.date(2000, 9, 12),
            Person.Sex.MALE, "bob@example.com"));

        return roster;
    }

}
```

Comment: How would you write this condition in simple `if(...)`?

Comment: char c = Character.toUpperCase(p.getName().charAt(0));
                      if( c >= 'A' && c <= 'C'){
                          return true;
                      }
                      return false;

Comment: this is the code I came up with for the anonymous version of the code. But  it doesn't works with lambda

Comment: Could you please give me a bit more hint?

Comment: nvm, I forgot to include {}.... thanks again for your help @Pshemo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use lambda, you might as well use stream too:

```
roster.stream()
      .filter(p -> p.getGender() == Sex.MALE
                && p.getName().matches("[a-cA-C].*"))
      .forEach(Person::printPerson);
```

Now, using `matches()` like that is not the best for performance, so that can be improved if performance becomes a problem.